# "Out Of Memory" when trying to export apk with ProGuard obfuscation

Tags: java, android, eclipse, out-of-memory, proguard

Everytime I try to export my project with ProGuard obfuscation, it shows "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space".

It won't show the error if I export with "-dontobfuscate" parameter, but this makes my use of ProGuard useless.

I tried to use -Xms256M -Xmx1024M(also 1536 and 2048) at different places, but it won't work. Wierd thing is when I look at the Task Manager, it stopped at ~256MB. So I think I might used the parameters at the wrong places.

Please help, thank you. (Sorry for bad English)

Comment: Could you please explain exactly how are you using ProGuard? If you are running command line send it. If you are using other tool, explain. I believe that `-Xmx` option does not "arrive" where it should.

Answer (score 1):

How much RAM does the computer have?

Try to change/set, also using the -Xms256M -Xmx1024M values you mentioned, the NewSize, MaxNewSize, PermSize, MaxPermSize, etc. VM values, like, f.i.: -XX:NewSize=64m -XX:MaxNewSize=128m -XX:PermSize=64m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m

Try different values...

HIH

KL

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for late reply. Our programmers found that there is no crash with -dontoptimize. This should not be a good solution though.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the maximum heap size for Eclipse (and thus for ProGuard inside Eclipse) by changing the `-Xmx` value in `eclipse.ini`, in the base directory of Eclipse.